# Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

When running

```
Reduce[{p^3 + 3 p^2 (1 - p)[1 - q (1 - q)^2] + 
3 p (1 - p)[q^2 (1 - q)] <= p, 
    p >= 0,
    p <= 1, 
    q >= 0,
    q <= 1}, 
    {p, q}]
```

I get the error message:

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
```

I don't use Mathematica very often so I am not sure about the syntax.

1. Am I doing something wrong or is it really a problem `Reduce` cannot solve?
2. If so, can the problem be solved using any other Mathematica function? (Or do you see a way to massage the problem in order to get a solution?)
3. Or is it just that the problem does not have a better closed-form solution than $p^3 + 3 p^2 (1 - p)[1 - q (1 - q)^2] + 3 p (1 - p)[q^2 (1 - q)] \leq p$ itself?

Here is the graphical solution on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vkfe0svfd5.

I guess $p^3 + 3 p^2 (1 - p)[1 - q (1 - q)^2] + 3 p (1 - p)[q^2 (1 - q)] - p$ is simply the polynomial describing the "curvy" boundary and there's no better way to put it (3.)?

Comment: Don't use [] as parentheses, as [] is strictly for function application. See [The four kinds of bracketing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

Comment: Also, the ordering of variables matters. Reduce[system, {q, p}] or simply Reduce[system] returns a much nicer solution than Reduce[system, {p, q}].

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, big time newbie mistake, sorry about that. Any alternative parenthesis you're allowed to use for clarity? I guess I can look it up myself...

Comment: @aooiiii, thanks for the tip, makes a lot of sense given the Desmos graph...

Comment: If either of you wants to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it and close the matter. Otherwise, I'll answer myself at some point.

Answer (score 1):

As Carl Woll wrote in the comments:

> Don't use [] as parentheses, as [] is strictly for function application. See [The four kinds of bracketing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html).

Also, as aaooiiii wrote in the comments:

> The ordering of variables matters. `Reduce[system, {q, p}]` or simply `Reduce[system]` returns a much nicer solution than `Reduce[system, {p, q}]`